# MIPS deprecation warning

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have removed mips, but am still getting the warning

Error:(81) Android NDK: Application targets deprecated ABI(s): mips64
Error:(82) Android NDK: Support for these ABIs will be removed in a future NDK release.
Error:(82) Android NDK: Support for these ABIs will be removed in a future NDK release.
Error:(81) Android NDK: Application targets deprecated ABI(s): mips

```
Application.mk 
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a x86
APP_PLATFORM := android-10
```

**UPDATES**

build.gradle for ndk

```
 sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []
  externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
      path 'src/main/jni/Android.mk'
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your Application.mk is being used? What does your build.gradle look like?

Comment: see updates in original post

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by adding:

```
    android {
    .
    .
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
                abiFilters 'x86'
                abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
                moduleName "your-library-name"
         }
```

to the app/build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Android Studio was not removing the previous cached NDK builds from the .externalNativeBuild directory from my project.  After manually deleting them the process build correctly with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

go to files and click invalidate cache/restart